# Go Handling HTTPS requests in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, go, https, ssl-certificate

In GAE I just use a default domain name: **https://*.appspot.com**, so I don't need to generate self-signed certificates.

Google App Engine docs specify how app.yaml should be configured to serve SSL connections:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_secure

But to serve an HTTPS connection in Go I write the following code example where I need to specify the certificates' filenames:

```
import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    go http.ListenAndServeTLS(Address, "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil)
}
```

I don't understand how in this case to serve SSL requests if I don't generate certificates myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `http.ListenAndServeTLS` on App Engine.  If you have your `app.yaml` set up correctly, traffic will be served over SSL for you.  A minimal App Engine app might be something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hi")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check it soon